# Is "do-almost-nothing" ever winning on large CHOMP boards?

Tags: co.combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

*This is a special case of [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4750402/when-is-do-almost-nothing-a-good-idea-in-chomp) asked but unanswered at MSE:*

Consider the combinatorial game [CHOMP](https://wiki.math.wisc.edu/images/Chomp_Sol.pdf) (presented as in the linked notes so that the "poison" square is bottom-left). In any $2$-by-$n$ board, the "almost-passing" move (taking the top-right square) is winning; moreover, whenever it is a winning move, it is the *only* winning move. Intiutively I would expect it to be "usually" bad, but I don't see that it is:

> Are there $m$-by-$n$ CHOMP boards on which "almost-passing" is a winning move for player 1, but with $\min\{m,n\}$ arbitrarily large?

<s>Embarrassingly, I don't even know of an example going above $2$.</s> Turns out there's a few - computer search has verified $6\times 11$, $6\times 15$, and $6\times 27$ (thanks to Peter Taylor and Sam Benner in the comments below). This raises a natural related question: are there infinitely many $n$ for which the $6\times n$-game is of this type?

Comment: (I was going to make a comment about how this move is important in the strategy-stealing argument that Chomp is a 1st player win, but I see you mention that as motivation in the MSE question, so I'm just leaving this parenthetical instead...)

Comment: @SamHopkins Oh indeed! That argument is my all-time favorite proof in mathematics, by the way, partly for nostalgiac reasons: it (circuitously) played a non-negligible role in getting me into logic.

Comment: Your memory appears incorrect, but if we assume you misremembered $\max$ for $\min$ some quick calculation shows $6\times 11$ as an example.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Embarrassingly, I'm not seeing it; what's the quick calculation? (Maybe my coffee hasn't kicked in yet ...)

Comment: Other than $2×n$, $6×11$ is the smallest example, and $6×15$ the next smallest.  I'll let you know when my computer reaches $6×19$...

Comment: $6×19$ doesn't work, but $6×27$ does.

Comment: @SamBenner Neat! I've incorporated these facts into the question itself.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "computation" rather than "calculation". My program gets up to $6 \times 11$ in a few seconds, but didn't get as far as $14 \times 14$ in six hours.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That makes me feel better, I thought you meant "quick _human_ calculation."

Comment: I suggest we call it simply the minimal move instead of the "do-almost-nothing" move or the "almost passing" move, as the latter are cumbersome and not more descriptive than "minimal". But those phrases do seem fine to help motivate the question.

Answer (score 5):

Using this code, I've searched up to $15×15$ and $6×65$.  Improved memory management is required to go further.  The only large (not $2×n$) boards on which the minimal move is winning in this range are $6×11$, $6×15$, and $6×27$.

Per [my answer on the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4765462), there are a finite number of boards $m×n$ for which the minimal move is winning for every $m$, so I conjecture that these are all the $6×n$ boards.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::unordered_map<std::string, bool> cache;

std::string getCacheString(std::vector<int> const &game){
    std::ostringstream ss;
    std::copy(game.begin(), game.end()-1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(ss, ","));
    ss << game.back();
    return ss.str();
}

int checkCache(std::vector<int> const &game){
    std::string str = getCacheString(game);
    if (cache.find(str) != cache.end()){
        return cache[str];
    }
    return 2;
}

void addCache(std::vector<int> const &game, bool result){
    std::string str = getCacheString(game);
    // std::cout << "Added " << str << " to cache: " << result << std::endl;
    cache[str] = result;
}

bool checkGame(std::vector<int> game);

bool checkMove(std::vector<int> game, int x, int y){
    if (y == 0){
        while (x < game.size()){
            game.pop_back();
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = x; i < game.size(); i++){
            game[i] = y < game[i] ? y : game[i];
        }
    }
    int prevScore = checkCache(game);
    if (prevScore == 2){
        return checkGame(game);
    }
    return prevScore;
}

bool checkGame(std::vector<int> game){
    for (int i = 0; i < game.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < game[i]; j++){
            if (i == 0 && j == 0) continue;
            if (!checkMove(game, i, j)){
                addCache(game, true);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    addCache(game, false);
    return false;
}

int main(){
    cache["1"] = false;
    for (int i = 3; i < 1000; i++){
        bool result = checkGame({i, i, i, i, i, i-1});
        std::cout << i << ": " << result << std::endl;
    }
}
```
````

Comment: I guess "up to $15\times15$ and $6\times65$" means "all $m\times n$ where either $m\le15$ and $n\le15$ or else $m\le6$ and $n\le65$"?

Comment: @bof Yes, that's correct.